# swap between windows in ubuntu aka multiple work spaces(like swaping between app pages in android and iOS)

Tags: 14.04, multiple-desktops

Can I have multiple work spaces in ubuntu. Is there a program that fixes this or can I do this by default. I don't mean the ctrl + tab command I want to have several working spaces that I can easily switch between. I have seen people do this in mac so I thought this would work on linux as well?

Take android and iOS for example then you can just switch between the different app screens. So I would like to have like several desktops and at the first desktop I do something and on the second desktop I do another thing and on the third desktop...

Thx Tobias, it worked!
Only one problem now is that I have the same program menu in all work spaces. I hoped to get a new program menu when I switch to a new workspace. How do I fix this?

Comment: Although this is completely possible with the default Unity desktop, I would suggest installing the Gnome desktop environment. It has work spaces enabled by default, and it is easy to access (just move mouse cursor to the upper left corner of the screen).

Comment: Okay. I did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop and where prompted to choose gdm or light gdm and I choosed gdm. When I then logged in I choosed GNOME instead of ubuntu (I also had an option for GNOME classic). When logged in nothing seems to be different. Which changes should I see and what "additional options should be available". What should I do? Any solution will suite fine doesn't matter if it is gnome desktop, ubuntu desktop or something else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you logged into Gnome instead of Ubuntu, the typical unity sidebar should now be gone. When you move your mouse to the upper left corner, the Gnome sidebar should appear on the left, and the workspace selection should appear on the right. You will also see a preview of all open windows in your current workspace in the center of the screen. You can drag and drop windows between workspaces here, as well as quickly switch between tasks on the same workspace.

Comment: See my screenshot here:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByP_xymUIS0FUnJKeHZVTUgxdTA&authuser=0

Comment: okay so I got it to work in ubuntu actually like I wanted. I'm quite noobish in linux so I didn't recognize at first that I only needed to open a new terminal in the new workspace and open an application from the terminal to get it local in the workspace window. Program menu is global so when I tried to run application it run the program that were already running.Unfortunate when I installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop it f*cked up my ubuntu apearence. The optimal were to run it on ubuntu and when it works then I want to unintsall the gnome desktop and reinstall the ubuntu desktop. I start new thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible. 
Open System Settings from the menu in the top right corner. Double click on 'Appearance' click on the 'Behaviour' tab, and then check the 'Enable workspaces' checkbox.