# malfunctioning ubuntu desktop due to installation of gnome desktop

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I did sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop as in my previous thread: [swap between windows in ubuntu aka multiple work spaces(like swaping between app pages in android and iOS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560704/swap-between-windows-in-ubuntu-aka-multiple-work-spaceslike-swaping-between-app)

And now my ubuntu desktop is acting strangely. I don't have any background(can set one), background is just black. And some fonts in ubuntu seems to be gnome fonts now instead.

I multiboot ubuntu with windows 8.1 and I use grub. Before when I booted the machine grub were purple like ubuntu style but now it is grey like gnome style.

So how do I get rid of the gnome desktop and reinstall the ubuntu desktop? Or is there a better solution. It may seem strange but I think that if I reinstalled ubuntu desktop first then it should work like normal since gnome work and that were installed as the latest. Then I would just uninstall gnome desktop? Or is this stupid also like my "attempt" to fix the first "problem".

UPDATE//My computer have freezed three times now due to this. All three times when I choosed to log in to ubuntu desktop. So I thought I would choose gnome and it works fine but then the background in gnome is now the background that were in ubuntu.

Comment: Please refrain from using profanities, even if you censor them out. It is unnecessary and distracts from your question. See the [Help Center](http://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
At log in screen, hit CTRL+ALt+F1 to enter into command-line log in. Log in using your username and password.

Do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select lightdm instead of gdm

Do `sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-gnome-dekstop` to fully remove Gnome and all of it's components/global configuration files

Do `sudo reboot now` to restart.

If you ever do want to try Gnome again, try `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`instead of ubuntu-gnome-desktop. It's just the DE, none of the additional components. ubuntu-gnome-desktop is meant to be a full replacement, whereas gnome-shell is just an additional work environment.

Comment: I also thought that CTRL+ALt+F1 would do it. But when I enter the login information it says "incorrect login". So I need to do in another way, I started a new thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/560830/how-do-i-login-when-ubuntu-stops-before-login-screen                                                             At least I get to the command-line log in which prompted me for username and password so it maybe should work with another command?

Comment: Did you ever set a password for root? If you log in as root, you can still do it. Also, try entering recovery mode by holding the shift key during boot. Then you can drop down to root command line from there.